# How to execute and append a script tag to the html element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have following script tag

```
<script src="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=rsb&c=28&pli=3326580&PluID=0&w=728&h=90&ord=|RANDOM|&ncu=$$|CLICK|$$"></script>
<noscript>
    <a href="|CLICK|http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=brd&FlightID=3326580&Page=&PluID=0&Pos=4688" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=bsr&FlightID=3326580&Page=&PluID=0&Pos=4688" border=0 width=728 height=90>
    </a>
</noscript>
```

This is executing when, I am simply adding to a html body segments.

But its not executing if I am adding this tag to a html element dynamically with jquery.

I also tried to convert it to dom using `jQuery('')` before appending to the html element.

Please see my jQuery code which, I am doing to execute this.

```
var testUrl = $('<script src="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=rsb&c=28&pli=3326580&PluID=0&w=728&h=90&ord=|RANDOM|&ncu=$$|CLICK|$$"></script><noscript><a href="|CLICK|http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=brd&FlightID=3326580&Page=&PluID=0&Pos=4688" target="_blank"><img src="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=bsr&FlightID=3326580&Page=&PluID=0&Pos=4688" border=0 width=728 height=90></a></noscript>');
$('#previewImgDiv').html(testUrl);
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Post the jQuery code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using [postscribe](https://github.com/krux/postscribe).that is specially for  Asynchronously write javascript